# Chrome bookmarks on Unity

Tags: google-chrome

I've tried lots of things to delete one bookmark from Unity but I can't do it. It's annoying because when I open Chrome, this "Application" replaces my Chrome. I don't know how to delete this. Please help me Thanks!

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was better for you to mention what you tried.

Anyway, this looks like a webapp, not a bookmark. See the folder:

`~/.local/share/applications`

you will find it and can delete it.

Otherwise you'll find it on `/usr/share/applications/`, but you need to open the file manager as root. To do this via GUI you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gksu nautilus`.

**Remember, once your work is done, close the privileged Nautilus window. You may break your system by fault.**

Comment: The bookmark was in ~/.local/share/applications . Thank you very much bro ;D